# use .map during component composition in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I can render the following completely fine:

```
    <Select
      defaultValue=''
    >
        <Option value='' />
        <Option value='one' />
        <Option value='two' />
    </Select>
```

but what I want to do is compose a collection of n number of custom Option components as children that will be used during the  component's render method:

```
    <Select
      defaultValue=''
    >
        {
          this.props.optionValues.map((value, i) =>
            <Option key={i} value={value} />
          )
        }
    </Select>
```

But I'm struggling and cant find much documentation about this context of rendering components specifically

Does this work at all or not make sense due to how jsx is?

Comment: Granted that your `this.props.optionValues` array looks like `['', 'one', 'two']` it will work fine. Have you tried it? You can experiment in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/y2pyo4229x).

Comment: literally your comment about the array's form is all I needed...yes it works!...I feel so dumb - thanks a lot - its been a long day ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendering arrays as children is perfectly valid if each element has a unique `key` prop like you have outlined in your question. Granted that your `this.props.optionValues` array looks like `['', 'one', 'two']` it will work fine.

**Example**

```js
function App(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <select>
        <option value="">Pick number</option>
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
      </select>
      <select>
        <option value="">Pick number</option>
        {props.optionValues.map((value, i) => (
          <option key={i} value={value}>
            {value}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App optionValues={["one", "two"]} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: It'd be better to also use `value` as the key rather than an index, yes? https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: @SamVK Yes, that would work well in this case as well. I was just building on the example in the question.

Comment: Idk, what if you pass in two custom  <Option ... /> components both with value=‘ ‘ - using the values as keys would break I think